# Does each screen in my Main.storyboard represent a scene in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Example of the screens that I am referring to]

Each of these screens is controlled by a view controller. Where my confusion comes from is that each screen can have multiple view controllers.

I am asking this question because I am trying to transition between these screens programatically. Would I need to create a new scene delegate to do so? Or should I just present the view controller of the new screen on top of the old screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your storyboard has three scenes. They represent three different view controllers. In this case, they correspond to three “screens” in the app.

If you want to transition from one to another, you’d generally add segues in your storyboard to transition from one scene to another. E.g. you might add a button on the first view controller and the <kbd>control</kbd> drag from the button on one scene to the next scene. Then, when a user taps on that button, the app will present the next scene.

---

As an aside, a minor terminology clarification: While a storyboard scene often represents a “screen” in your app, that’s not strictly true. Sometimes you have view controllers within view controllers. A common example might be a navigation controller, where you have a scene for the navigation controller (which is a type of view controller) and another scene for its root view controller. What you see on screen is both the navigation bar from the navigation controller and the views from the embedded view controller.

Comment: Another example is view controller containment. It's pretty easy these days to set up a container view in view controller A and have that container view host the content view of a child view controller. (An easy way to make this connection is with an embed segue.)